# Spring Security: BCryptPasswordEncoder works without matter if the Version and Strength values are changed

Tags: java, spring-security, bcrypt

With Spring Boot CLI is possible do the following:

```
spring encodepassword secret
```

Where that command prints

```
{bcrypt}$2a$10$ZjFpLGhApSqM1ftCBOPvt.3aV3l5dsRawW61ZCX2lbIqRq6afgzk6
```

Therefore the password `secret` is encoded to `{bcrypt}$2a$10$ZjFpLGhApSqM1ftCBOPvt.3aV3l5dsRawW61ZCX2lbIqRq6afgzk6`, observe the *$2a$10* and the *{bcrypt}* parts

Having declared:

```
@Bean
PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Is mandatory use the following:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("some_user")
            .password("{bcrypt}$2a$10$ZjFpLGhApSqM1ftCBOPvt.3aV3l5dsRawW61ZCX2lbIqRq6afgzk6")
            .authorities("ROLE_SOME_ROLE");
```

Observe is mandatory use `{bcrypt}`, more details in [PasswordEncoderFactories](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/factory/PasswordEncoderFactories.java) class (for the `createDelegatingPasswordEncoder` method), it because the [DelegatingPasswordEncoder](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java) class is used behind the scenes.

If I don't use

```
@Bean
PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}
```

and is replaced with only with:

```
@Bean
PasswordEncoder bcryptEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(BCryptVersion.$2A, 10);// or new BCryptPasswordEncoder()
}
```

**Observations:** from above

- `BCryptPasswordEncoder(BCryptVersion.$2A, 10)` or `new BCryptPasswordEncoder()` are practically the same, see the [BCryptPasswordEncoder](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.java) class more details
- observe the `$2A, 10` part, it matches against `$2a$10` (from the password).

Now is mandatory use:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("some_user")
            .password("$2a$10$ZjFpLGhApSqM1ftCBOPvt.3aV3l5dsRawW61ZCX2lbIqRq6afgzk6")
            .authorities("ROLE_SOME_ROLE");
```

Observe is mandatory **not** use `{bcrypt}`, it because the [DelegatingPasswordEncoder](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java) class is **not** used anymore behind the scenes. Otherwise login is not possible.

Until here all have sense

Now the confusion is the following:

If is used:

```
@Bean
PasswordEncoder bcryptEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(BCryptVersion.$2Y, 12);
}
```

**Observation**: now `$2Y, 12` is used and it is totally different than `$2A, 10` (and therefore than the `$2a$10` password part/section).

**Situation**
is possible do the login process yet. I assumed that must be not possible because the patterns are not the same. BTW I did do `clean compile` in the project.

So what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Observation: now $2Y, 12 is used and it is totally different than $2A, 10 (and therefore than the $2a$10 password part/section).`

Yes, but we dont generate a new salt when comparing, we use the salt on the password fetched from the database.

if we look up [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) about `bcrypt` we see the following about `$2Y`

> In June 2011, a bug was discovered in crypt_blowfish, a PHP implementation of BCrypt. It was mis-handling characters with the 8th bit set. They suggested that system administrators update their existing password database, replacing $2a$ with $2x$, to indicate that those hashes are bad (and need to use the old broken algorithm). They also suggested the idea of having crypt_blowfish emit $2y$ for hashes generated by the fixed algorithm.

> Nobody else, including canonical OpenBSD, adopted the idea of 2x/2y. This version marker change was limited to crypt_blowfish.

As the spring implementation that did not have this vulnerability `$2Y$` is essentially the same as `$2A$`.

When we look into the source code for `BCrypt#checkpw` we see the following:

```
/**
 * Check that a password (as a byte array) matches a previously hashed one
 * @param passwordb the password to verify, as a byte array
 * @param hashed the previously-hashed password
 * @return true if the passwords match, false otherwise
 * @since 5.3
 */
public static boolean checkpw(byte[] passwordb, String hashed) {
    return equalsNoEarlyReturn(hashed, hashpw(passwordb, hashed));
}
```

which passes in the fetched pwd as the second argument into [this function](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/77484018bb46a4bf67b9ad617bd2311a33382de4/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.java#L586).

```
public static String hashpw(byte passwordb[], String salt) {
    
    // omitted code

    // Here we extract the salt from the provided hashed password 
    real_salt = salt.substring(off + 3, off + 25);

    // omitted code
}
```

They will only check that you are providing a valid Version. After that they extract the salt from the password that is stored in the database then hash the password with that salt and then compare them.

The constructor settings will only be applied to newly hashed passwords.

Comment: Interesting, because in the bottom of the `BCryptPasswordEncoder` class has 3 versions, 2a,2y,2b

Comment: BTW do you mean: `BCrypt.checkpw` right? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/ad4497fb72bc236937e521d2d0ca143f92bada10/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.java#L742

Comment: borth functions, the function you listed, all it does is call this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/ad4497fb72bc236937e521d2d0ca143f92bada10/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.java#L572 to get the bytes and then calls the next. Why spring have done the design choice with version you have to ask them.

Comment: I wrote the second comment because I found an error and already fixed. is not `BCryptPasswordEncoder#checkpw`, must be `BCrypt#checkpw`